# Excel AVERAGEIF function in combination with MOD to average over every nth row not behaving as expected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to average every 4th row in Excel.

The following formula should give the correct result since every single part of the formula is calculated correctly (if I do everything step by step).

```
=AVERAGEIF(MOD(ROW(D20:D35)-ROW(D20),4),"=0",D20:D35)    # does not work

=MOD(ROW(D20:D35)-ROW(D20),4)   # returns correct values

=AVERAGEIF(N19#,"=0",D20:D35) # N19# is the return of =MOD(ROW(D20:D35)-ROW(D20),4), and the result is the correct average, as it should be in the top function when everything is nested in one function.
```

I am not sure why the nested function is not working.
Can anyone help?

I am using Excel 16.71 on a Mac.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your first formula will return an error because `AVERAGEIF` specifies that its first argument must be a **Range** and, in your case, that first argument is an **Array**.  OTOH, in your last formula, `N19#` is returning a **Range**, so the formula returns the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding range vs array. That clarifies why option 1 fails and the step by step approach returns the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Average Every Nth Row

- All three finish in under a second for 1M rows but it seems like `INDEX` is faster than `FILTER` and `FILTER` is faster than Ron Rosenfeld's modernized version.

```
=LET(Data,D20:D35,nth,4,
AVERAGE(INDEX(Data,SEQUENCE((ROWS(Data)-1)/nth+1,,,nth))))
```

```
=LET(Data,D20:D35,nth,4,
AVERAGE(FILTER(Data,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data)),nth)=1)))
```

```
=LET(Data,D20:D35,nth,4,
AVERAGE(IFERROR(Data*1/(MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data)),nth)=1),"")))
```

Comment: Thanks for these ways to get the average over every nth row value! I really appreciate it! I actually ended up with this `=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW($D$20:$D$35)-ROW($C$20),4)=0,D20:$D$35))` when I couldn't figure out why `AVERAGEIF` didn't work. But using `LET` is actually sleak. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(1/(MOD(ROW(D20:D35),4)=0)*D20:D35,""))
```

`AVERAGE` function ignores text, and the `""` is seen as text.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative function. I will try this. However, I used the standard AVERAGE combined with the standard IF function to get the result I needed in the end. My question was really more about the reason why the initial function failed so I understand what Excel is doing here (and what not).

Comment: @Ben Hopefully my response in the comments to your question answered that.